# How to deploy Openstack HA with services inside lxcs?

Tags: server, juju, openstack, high-availability

I am trying to deploy Openstack in HA environment where there are 3 nodes(controllers) which have charms deployed inside lxcs but I am having difficulty in deploying the charms inside lxcs on specific nodes.

I would like to deploy 3 units of a charm inside lxcs. i.e. *juju deploy -n 3 rabbitmq-server*

Is there any way I can use the *--to* flag for this?
i.e. juju deploy -n 3 rabbitmq-server --to lxc:0 lxc:1 lxc:2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `--to`, you can't specify `-n`, sorry. You have to run the command once for each unit, like in a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to make sure that your containers are running: `lxc-ls --fancy`. If not start them with `lxc-start -n lxc:0 --daemon`

Then you need to jump into each container with `lxc-attach -n lxc:0`, make sure you have OpenstackHA installed and running in each one of them (yes, that means installing it 3 times and wasting some bandwidht and disk space)

Once this is done you can do your Openstack stuff for which I admitedly can not help you much.

Comment: To save bandwidth you can set up a http proxy or use your own repository cache.

Answer (score 1):

If the units have to be places on specific nodes then do not use the num-units flag (-n).

Instead deploy the first unit using the command:

> juju deploy  rabbitmq-server --to lxc:0

Then add-units accordingly:

> juju add-unit rabbitmq-server --to lxc:1
>
> juju add-unit rabbitmq-server --to lxc:2